# Post videos to chatter public group and track people who didn't view it

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter

I put training videos in a public group in chatter. From the way it's configured right now, I don't have information on how many people viewed the training and how many didn't.

I want to be able to track people who have not viewed training videos and send them reminder emails.

Our Salesforce architect suggested using a visual force page to post to chatter - That would allow us to track who has been clicking on our link. However, one problem we noticed with this approach is that the video link doesn't appear as a nice snapshot in this case, it just appears as a hyperlink which doesn't look very user friendly.

What is the best way of solving this problem? How can we post training videos to public groups in chatter and be able to track and email people who didn't view the training?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple companies which allow you to post and watch videos directly in-line and within chatter. They also allow you to track the engagement analytics on an individual level.

If you want some more information, feel free to email me at jarrett.stewart@vidyard.com